# How to read data from hive table using flink sql client?

Tags: hive, apache-flink

I tried to read the data from hive table using the flink sql client as per the [flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/hive/hive_catalog/) but it failed. i can read the table meta information,but not the data.

here is my hive data:

```shell
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> create database testdb ;
No rows affected (2.048 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> use testdb ;
No rows affected (0.106 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> create table source (a bigint, b bigint) ;
No rows affected (1.026 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> show tables ;
+-----------+--+
| tab_name  |
+-----------+--+
| source    |
+-----------+--+
1 row selected (0.877 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> insert into source values (1, 1) ;
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. tez, spark) or using Hive 1.X releases.
No rows affected (7.498 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> select a, b from source ;
+----+----+--+
| a  | b  |
+----+----+--+
| 1  | 1  |
+----+----+--+
```

here is my flink sql client:

```html
Flink SQL> show catalogs ;
+-----------------+
|    catalog name |
+-----------------+
| default_catalog |
|          myhive |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set

Flink SQL> use catalog myhive ;
[INFO] Execute statement succeed.

Flink SQL> show databases ;
+---------------+
| database name |
+---------------+
|       default |
|        testdb |
+---------------+
2 rows in set

Flink SQL> use testdb ;
[INFO] Execute statement succeed.

Flink SQL> show tables ;
+------------+
| table name |
+------------+
|     source |
+------------+
1 row in set

Flink SQL> SET sql-client.execution.result-mode=tableau;
[INFO] Session property has been set.

Flink SQL> select a, b from source ;
Empty set
```

I have added a new project to quickly reproduce this error: https://github.com/lianxmfor/flink-hive

Comment: hi, have you tried creating table in flink side with connector=hive parameter? `create table source (a bigint, b bigint) with('connector'='hive') ;` this should create a table that flink already knows its points to a hive connector.